# Print and Index Issues On Debugging

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

```
import yt
import glob

#Give path to particle files
f_parts = glob.glob("home/richard/pure_det_hdf5_part_*")
f_parts.sort()

#Give fields to be included in the trajectories. Positions are added by default.
fields = ["particle_dens", "particle_temp", "particle_velocity_x", "particle_velocity_y"]

#Get indices of all available  particles
#ds = yt.load(f_parts[0])
print("f_parts =", f_parts)
dd = ds.all_data()
indices = dd["particle_index"].astype("int64")
#Create individual '.dat' files for every particle
ts = yt.DatasetSeries(f_parts[100])
trajs = ts.particle_trajectories(indices, fields=fields)
trajs.write_out("traj")
```

Output:

```
File "C:\Users\rocke\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\richard\untitled0.py", line 18, in <module>
    ds = yt.load(f_parts[0])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have been trying to find the bug in what is causing my error, but I have been having an issue with getting an error-free print on what the matter is with the f_parts.

Comment: I don't understand, the commented line `#ds = yt.load(f_parts[0])` is causing error. Have you commented after ther error or what? try `len(f_parts)` to check if the list is empty or not

Comment: I was advised by my professor to comment the yt.load statement out, print out f_parts, e.g., as a print (“f_parts = “, f_parts).

ds I know should be not commented out, but he said it should be for debugging.

Comment: But the error that you have given is caused by this line. How can a commented line raise error?

Comment: Oops, that is a typo on my part once I looked at it. It gives me an issue on leaving it alone and not commenting it out in terms of range, which I was told to leave it to the adult of 0 in this case as 71 is not working. 

Still, how would you get a printout of the indices of that line though? Since I typed it out and only the index is out of range still.